# OSX MacPorts Subversion Install Error

Tags: macos, svn, macports

I first installed JavaHL from Macports to enable Subclipse and I had no issues.

```
sudo port install subversion-javahlbindings +no_bdb +universal
```

Then I went to install the full Subversion Client:

```
sudo port install subversion
```

and I received the following error (see below) - any idea how to correct this?

```
:info:configure checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin12.2.0 dyld
:info:configure checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
:info:configure configure: building both shared and static libraries
:info:configure checking whether libtool needs -no-undefined... no
:info:configure checking whether to avoid circular linkage at all costs... no
:info:configure checking for trang... none
:info:configure checking for doxygen... none
:info:configure checking for Expat... yes
:info:configure checking for socket in -lsocket... no
:info:configure checking for availability of Berkeley DB... no
:info:configure configure: error: Berkeley DB 4.0.14 or newer wasn't found.
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_subversion/subversion/work/subversion-1.7.6" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-berkeley-db=:/opt/local/include/db46:/opt/local/lib/db46:db-4.6 --with-neon=/opt/local --with-apr=/opt/local/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/opt/local/bin/apu-1-config --without-apxs --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --disable-neon-version-check --with-serf=/opt/local --with-sasl=/opt/local
:info:configure Exit code: 1
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port subversion returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: targets not executed for subversion: org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:configure Please see the log file for port subversion for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_subversion/subversion/main.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed the bindings port with the `no_bdb` variant, try the same for the `subversion` client port:

```
sudo port clean subversion
sudo port install subversion +no_bdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Ports can be quite unreliable, especially when you have many libs/binaries installed.  I recently deleted my entire /opt/local directory and restarted with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), much more reliable.